# Converting column of DataFrame into Series-Python

Tags: dataframe, series

I am working with breast cancer data and I donot understand why the column is not converting into series when assigned to a variable.

```
df['target'].shape
```

this gives (569,) but

```
b=df['target']
b.shape
```

gives (569,1). I want b to be a series not DataFrame